# Copying depth render buffer to the depth buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Currently I am rendering some stuff to a FBO with an attached depth render buffer.

However, after I am done with the render buffer, the depth information is pretty much lost.

How can I copy the data from the render buffer to the fixed function depth buffer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [glBlitFramebuffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBlitFramebuffer), enabling the `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` flag.

Example code:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_id);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

glBlitFramebuffer(offset_x, offset_y, offset_x + size_x, offset_y + size_y,
                  offset_x, offset_y, offset_x + size_x, offset_y + size_y,
                  GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT,
                  GL_NEAREST);
```

This will copy *only* the depth buffer.

Comment: I actually had a quick question about this? It copies the depth buffer from the FBO to the default frame buffer's depth buffer but if you wish to visualise the depth data as an RGB image, is there a way you can copy the depth values to the color buffer instead (the color buffer of the window frame buffer)? Or do you to render to texture if you wish to to that?