# OpenGL invalid operation: copy depth render buffer to default depth buffer

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, depth-buffer

I tried to follow [Copying depth render buffer to the depth buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315534/copying-depth-render-buffer-to-the-depth-buffer) but it does not work for me. Here is my complete example:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned int uint;

int main()
{
    if (glfwInit() != 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    const uint width = 256;
    const uint height = 256;

    if (glfwOpenWindow(width, height, 8, 8, 8, 0, 24, 0, GLFW_WINDOW) != 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        std::cerr << glewGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    GLuint r;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &r);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, r);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

    GLuint r2;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &r2);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, r2);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA4, width, height);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

    GLuint f;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &f);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, f);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, r);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, r2);
    std::cout << (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) << std::endl;
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    std::cout << gluErrorString(glGetError()) << std::endl;

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, f);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

    std::cout << gluErrorString(glGetError()) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output I get:

```
1
no error
invalid operation
```

The `24` in `glfwOpenWindow` is the number of depth bits. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you attaching a color renderbuffer when you are only using a depth buffer?

Comment: I wanted the framebuffer to be complete as I am not sure if it has any influence.

Comment: The code does not give an invalid operation for me. You could try with an 8-bit stencil (e.g. GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8).

Comment: Yes `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8` works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ThomasD suggested in the comments `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8` worked.

Comment: That's all well and good, but since the original code worked fine on his machine, it's more important people coming to look at this question in the future to understand why it failed on your machine and succeeded on his.  Especially since someone else running different drivers / hardware might not be able to find success just by changing the stencil format in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters to `glfwOpenWindow` are specifying the desired values.  However, it's entirely possible that your driver doesn't support the exact format you're asking for (24 bit color, 24 bit depth, no alpha, no stencil).  GLFW will attempt to find the best match while meeting your minimums.

In this case it's probably giving you the most standard format of RGBA color (32 bit) and a 24/8 bit depth/stencil buffer, or it could be creating a 32 bit depth buffer.  You'd actually need to call `glfwGetWindowParam` to query the depth and stencil bits for the default framebuffer, and then build your renderbuffers to match that.